# eliminating gaps in inline list

Tags: enumitem

Here's an anonymized list I'm using. Is there a way to eliminate the gaps within?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description*}{4}
\setlist[mylist]{align=left,leftmargin=0em} 

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item[XXXX XXXXX XXX] XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXX
  \begin{mylist}
    \item [X XX]
      \begin{mylist}
      \item[XXX] XXXXX XX XXXXXXX XXXXXX XXX [XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX] XXX XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX
      \end{mylist}
    \item[X XXX] XXXXXXXXXX
      \begin{mylist}
      \item[XXX] [X]XX [XXXXXX] XXXXX XXXXXX XXX XXX XXXX XXXXXXXX
      \end{mylist}
      \item[X XX] XXXXXXXXXX
        \begin{mylist}
        \item[XXX] XXX [XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXX X]XXXXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XX XXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX []  XXXXXXXX XX XXX XXXXXXXX XX X XXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX[]
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

PS: `align=parleft` solves the problem but then the labels overlap with the items.

[image]

PS2: with the addition in the preamble of

```
\usepackage[english]{babel} % set the applicable language module
\hyphenation{saddle-point break-through}
```

Here's a blurred version of the original
[image]

PS3: to answer the no-hyphenation critique.

```
  \begin{mylist}
  \item[Jaw. Ahem. XYZ] AHEM PIZZAS JAZZLIKE JOCKEY BACKPACKING JAZZLIKE MIX BLACKJACKS
  \begin{mylist}
    \item [X 12]
      \begin{mylist}
      \item[(X)] jockey ok jacuzzi pizzas mix [blackjacks ok jazzlike unpublicized blackjacks] mix jacuzzi ahem pizzaz oxygenizing
      \end{mylist}
    \item[X 123] BLACKJACK.
      \begin{mylist}
      \item[(a)] [M]ix [jockey] jockey pizzas mix mix ahem jazzlike
      \end{mylist}
      \item[X 12] blackjack.
        \begin{mylist}
        \item[(a)] mix [jacuzzi ahem pizzas b]lacksjacks jockey jazzlike pizzas ok mix pizzas backpacking jukeboxes mix jazzlike jukeboxes[]  jazzlike ok mix jazzlike ok z ahem pizzas blackjacks[]
      \end{mylist}
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
```

Comment: You should use natural words, which can be hyphenated.

Comment: @Zarko each sequence of X's is a natural word that has been anonymized: `[[:alnum:]]->X`.

Comment: but can not be hyphenated. BTW, nested inline list quite unusual. As you show, in text it is impossible to recognise, when start nested list.

Comment: "As you show, in text it is impossible to recognise, when start nested list. " indeed, that would show in the labels.

Comment: why do you use lists, if they have a single `\item` each? Simpler to use `\textbf` for example and some custom spacing for label.

Comment: @user691586 it's coincidental that this list has single `\item` per level. Tomorrow I may revise it and have more than one. Also, I use reference to labels.

Comment: You do have to code some extras using a counter and `\refstepcounter` appropriately, perhaps even you need two (2) counters: one for list, one for item, subordinate to list one, but that is not a lot to do and is about all you seem to really need about lists. In short perhaps easier to roll-out your own macros here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want `mode=unboxed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{description*}{4}
\setlist[mylist]{align=left,leftmargin=0em,mode=unboxed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
\item[Jaw. Ahem. XYZ] AHEM PIZZAS JAZZLIKE JOCKEY BACKPACKING JAZZLIKE MIX BLACKJACKS
  \begin{mylist}
  \item [X 12]
    \begin{mylist}
    \item[(X)] jockey ok jacuzzi pizzas mix [blackjacks ok jazzlike unpublicized 
               blackjacks] mix jacuzzi ahem pizzaz oxygenizing
    \end{mylist}
  \item[X 123] BLACKJACK.
    \begin{mylist}
    \item[(a)] [M]ix [jockey] jockey pizzas mix mix ahem jazzlike
    \end{mylist}
  \item[X 12] blackjack.
    \begin{mylist}
    \item[(a)] mix [jacuzzi ahem pizzas b]lacksjacks jockey jazzlike pizzas ok mix 
               pizzas backpacking jukeboxes mix jazzlike jukeboxes[]  jazzlike ok mix 
               jazzlike ok z ahem pizzas blackjacks[]
    \end{mylist}
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]